# UnsupportedOperationException: Serializables don't support default values - Jetpack Compose Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using Jetpack Compose Navigation to pass a Health instance to another composable. The below code shows my health class and my Destination.

Health.kt:

```kotlin
data class Health(
    val height: Int,
    val weight: Int,
    val age: Int,
    val gender: Gender
) : Serializable

enum class Gender: Serializable { Male, Female }
```

NavDestination.kt

```kotlin
                        composable(
                            route = "result/{health}",
                            arguments = listOf(
                                navArgument("health") {
                                    type =
                                        NavType.SerializableType(Health::class.java)
                                }
                            )
                        ) { backStackEntry ->
                            val health = (backStackEntry.arguments?.getSerializable("health") as? Health) ?: return@composable
                            ResultScreen(navActions = navActions, health = health)
                        }
```

NavActions.kt

```kotlin
val navigateToResultScreen = { health: Health ->
        navController.navigate("result/{$health}")
    }
```

However, I'm getting this error according to the logcat. Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

```kotlin
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.octagon_technologies.bmicalculator, PID: 20788
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Serializables don't support default values.
        at androidx.navigation.NavType$SerializableType.parseValue(NavType.java:838)
        at androidx.navigation.NavType$SerializableType.parseValue(NavType.java:791)
        at androidx.navigation.NavType.parseAndPut(NavType.java:96)
        at androidx.navigation.NavDeepLink.parseArgument(NavDeepLink.java:299)
        at androidx.navigation.NavDeepLink.getMatchingArguments(NavDeepLink.java:260)
        at androidx.navigation.NavDestination.matchDeepLink(NavDestination.java:474)
        at androidx.navigation.NavGraph.matchDeepLink(NavGraph.java:79)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1034)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1017)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostControllerKt.navigate(NavHostController.kt:107)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostControllerKt.navigate$default(NavHostController.kt:106)
        at com.octagon_technologies.bmicalculator.ui.navigation.NavActions$navigateToResultScreen$1.invoke(NavActions.kt:9)
        at com.octagon_technologies.bmicalculator.ui.navigation.NavActions$navigateToResultScreen$1.invoke(NavActions.kt:8)
        at com.octagon_technologies.bmicalculator.ui.screens.home.HomeScreenKt$HomeScreen$1$6.invoke(HomeScreen.kt:122)
        at com.octagon_technologies.bmicalculator.ui.screens.home.HomeScreenKt$HomeScreen$1$6.invoke(HomeScreen.kt:120)
        at com.octagon_technologies.bmicalculator.ui.components.home.CalculateBtnKt$CalculateButton$1$1$1.invoke(CalculateBtn.kt:29)
        at com.octagon_technologies.bmicalculator.ui.components.home.CalculateBtnKt$CalculateButton$1$1$1.invoke(CalculateBtn.kt:29)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why this couldn't work: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148523779

"`Serializable` and `Parcelable` have no consistent API surface that would allow automatic parsing of a string into your custom class instance. That's why `parseValue` throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`."

It's expected that you'll only pass ids in this deep links, not full objects

Workaround:

```
composable(
    route = "result",
    arguments = listOf(
        navArgument("health") {
            type =
                NavType.SerializableType(Health::class.java)
        }
    )
) {
    val health = (navController.previousBackStackEntry.arguments?.getSerializable("health") as? Health) ?: return@composable
    ResultScreen(navActions = navActions, health = health)
}
```

Navigate like this:

```
navController.currentBackStackEntry
    ?.arguments?.putSerializable("health", health)
navController.navigate("result")
```

Comment: Looks like a nice workaround. Unfortunately, when I try it, `navController.currentBackStackEntry.arguments` and `navController.previousBackStackEntry.arguments` are always null. Is there something missing from your example? Maybe something special in the way you initialise `navController`?  All examples I've seen so far just have ```val navController = rememberNavController()```.

Comment: @MylesBennett `previousBackStackEntry ` should be available if you have a previous screen in the stack. It's easy to check out - does pressing back button leads to the previous screen or closes the app? Do you have any parameters specified with `navController.navigate`?

Comment: So this is just a really simple project I set up just to test this exact functionality. There are two screens/stack entries. I'm trying to move from the first screen to the second passing a serializable data object from that first screen to the second. Pressing back from the first screen will obviously exit the app.
At some point, something has to set `arguments` to something non-null.  I guess I'm missing that bit. And yes, I had parameters set in `navController.navigate`, including a dummy for the first screen.

Comment: @PhilDukhov Can you please help me out over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73650798/how-pass-parcelable-object-with-new-version-of-compose-navigation?noredirect=1#comment130059237_73650798

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but I've fixed it using the Gson library, which is used for encoding & decoding classes from `JSON`.

Will to use it you will convert your `Class` into `JSON` as a `String` and pass it into a navigation argument as a `String` type then you'll decode it from `String` which the `JSON` code into your `Class` again.

> Example of use

```
navController.navigate("result/${Gson().toJson($health)}")
```

> Now for decoding our `Class` again

```
composable(
    route = "result/{health}",
    arguments = listOf(navArgument("health") { type = NavType.StringType })
) { backStackEntry ->
    val healthAsJson = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("health")
    val health = Gson().fromJson(healthAsJson, Health::class.java)
    ResultScreen(navActions = navActions, health = health)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of passing a complex Object around, it's better to pass an id and retrieve it by the id. The [Navigation documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#retrieving-complex-data) states the following:

> It is strongly advised not to pass around complex data objects when navigating, but instead pass the minimum necessary information, such as a unique identifier or other form of ID, as arguments when performing navigation actions