# Serializable don't support default values

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

```
composable(
            "studentMainPage/{studentObject}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("studentObject") {
                    type = NavType.SerializableType(Student::class.java)
                 })
        ) {
            val studentObject = it.arguments?.getSerializable(
                "studentObject",Student::class.java
            )!!

            StudentMainPage(navController = navController, studentObject = studentObject)
        }
```

```
val studentObject1=Student(0,"","","","","","","","")
                        navController.navigate("studentMainPage/${studentObject}"){
                            popUpTo("studentEntryPage"){inclusive=true}
                        }
```

I'm taking "Serializable don't support default values" error.What's happening to navigation ? I'm working on it for 2 days.Please help me

I tried parcelable but it didn't work.And there is gson solve problem but it is not original method.That's why i want to use original method in my project.I searched much time in documentation but I didn't find any solve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnsupportedOperationException: Serializables don't support default values - Jetpack Compose Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67176035/unsupportedoperationexception-serializables-dont-support-default-values-jetp)

Comment: Basically you have to pass the serialized Object as an argument to `currentBackStackEntry` when navigating and retrieve it from there afterwards.

Comment: Please can you give any link or can you explain shortly about currentBackStackEntry thank you for your help @BenjyTec

Comment: See this [https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-with-args](official documentation section), it shows an example and some explanation.

Comment: Okay @BenjyTec  thank you .I will do it.Thanks for help

Comment: @BenjyTec i have last question. Is it just working when device is API>=33? Because it's pushing me to put annotation like `@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)`

Comment: It should work from API21. Which exact code line is giving you the warning that API33 is required?

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake.I imported wrong library .Thanks bro